# Which hook occurs last before rendering the exposed filter widgets?

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to edit the variables that go from Views into the form array editted by `hook_form_alter()` and the tpl file `views-exposed-form.tpl.php`. Specifically, I'm trying to use the contents of `$view->exposed_input` for form theming, without resorting to using `$view = views_get_current_view();`

I've tried working my way up [the order of execution defined here](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7.x-3.x):

> - hook_views_pre_view
> - hook_views_pre_build
> - hook_views_post_build
> - hook_views_pre_execute
> - hook_views_post_execute
> - hook_views_pre_render
> - hook_views_post_render

...but I'm stuck. At `hook_views_pre_render()`, `$view->exposed_widgets` gives me already-rendered HTML, so it's clearly too late, but the earlier ones don't give me anything at all.

Based on [How to choose between all the views hooks?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/180141/how-to-choose-between-all-the-views-hooks), I've tried using a preprocess hook based on the tpl file name, like `hook_preprocess_views_exposed_form()`, but the view isn't in scope here, I'm looking for the last views hook before this where I can find data from the view to these variables.

What I want to do, is take the contents of `$view->exposed_input`, and pass it through to the exposed form `tpl` file so that I can add a facet-like summary of current filters to my view. Which is the Views hook where I can do this?

I'm using Better Exposed Filters module, so if there are any hooks or tricks specific to that,they'd be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what you need by adding a custom property to your form array via form alter:

```
function yourmodule_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  // get the related view
  $view = $form_state['view'];

  // get the exposed_input and store it into a custom property
  $form['#exposed_input'] = $view->exposed_input; 

}
```

The form array is directly available as a variable in your `views-exposed-form.tpl.php`, try adding the following to the end of that tpl file:

```
<pre><?php print_r($form['#exposed_input']); ?></pre>
```

Hope this helps!